# github oauth with multiple domains

Tags: oauth-2.0, multi-tenant, github-api

i am running an application that runs on several subdomains usergroupXYZ.onruby.de and also supports arbitrary domains as aliases. so you can access the domain via yourusergroup.onruby.de or via customdomain.de.

the app provides logins via twitter oauth and github oauth2.

the problem is, that i did not find a way to support github auth via custom domains. i always get `redirect_uri_mismatch` errors from github.

the twitter auth does not have a problem with redirecting to a different domain.

does anyone have a solution to this problem other than creating a github application token for each custom domain?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can override the callback URL but it must match the host name in the OAuth Application settings.  This document gives a list of good and bad matches: http://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/#redirect-urls

Since different contexts are allowed, one solution would be to create different contexts on a base callback URL and then using the context information to redirect to the specific host.  It would mean that you would be acting like a 'broker' and would need to pass some information to the target host.

If your callback URL is `oauth.onruby.de`, then `oauth.onruby.de/cust1` and `oauth.onruby.de/cust2` will be valid according to Github.  You can then redirect `/cust1` to `cust1.de` and `/cust2` to `cust2.de`.

Please keep in mind that `oauth.onruby.de` would be acting as a gateway or broker and it would need to ensure that there are no security exposures.

Answer (score 2):

Yep we did what Akber suggested. We have two sites, `xxx.com` and `xxx.co.uk` and we want to use One github app for both sites OAuth.

We used Rails and OmniAuth gem.

The first thing we need to do is to append `com` or `co.uk` to the end of the callback URL

```
class OmniAuth::Strategies::GitHub
  # Some code are omitted    

  def callback_url
    url = super
    matches = url.match(/xxx\.([a-z|\.]+)(:\d+)?\//)
    if matches && matches[1] != 'com'
      tld = matches[1]
      url.gsub!("xxx.#{matches[1]}", 'xxx.com')
      url << "/#{tld}"
    end

    url
  end
end
```

and here's the rails middleware code that does redirect when github OAuth calls back

```
def call(env)
    match = env["PATH_INFO"].match(/\A\/users\/auth\/github\/callback\/(.+)\Z/)
    if match
      host = env["HTTP_HOST"]
      [301, {"Location" => "#{env['rack.url_scheme']}://#{host.gsub('com', match[1])}/users/auth/github/callback?#{env["QUERY_STRING"]}"}, self]
    else
      @app.call(env)
    end
end
```